# how to make regex differentiate between adjacent groups?

Tags: regex

Lets say I have this string I want to parse:
`"this is my #{part1}#{part2}" string."`

If I use this current regex: `(#{(.*)})`

I get these strings returned:

1. #{part1} #{part2}
2. part1}#{part2

Is there any way I can make regex to return group 1 as `#{part1}`, and `#{part2}` separately, as well as group 2 return as `part1`, `part2`

Edit: realized I am stupid, the pattern should be `(#{(.+?)})` to match as few as possible. I would delete but apparently thats a no-no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the pattern should be `(#{(.+?)})`